# Cherry-pick is not happening , shows the fatal :not a git repository how do I solve this

Tags: git, gerrit, cherry-pick

I want the latest changes from gerrit and need to pick the changes to putty. How can I pick Changes from gerrit to putty.

Answer (score 0):

I see “Not a git repo” when I’m in a non git directory.  So, to start, make sure git status works from the directory you’re in and you have a .git directory in the base directory of your repo.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to clone the repository from Gerrit:

1. Sign in to the Gerrit UI
2. Click on BROWSE > Repositories
3. Find the repository using the "Filter" field
4. Click on the "Repository Name"
5. Copy the clone command from the "Download" section
6. Execute the clone command in the terminal

Then you can use the "cd" command to enter in the local repository directory, and cherry-pick the commit you want.